# PyTorch Installation Error - Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

Tags: pytorch

Hello there! I’ve been trying to install PyTorch, but so far all I got is error messages. I tried the command line

```
pip install torch==1.8.1+cpu torchvision==0.9.1+cpu torchaudio===0.8.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

that was given on the tutorial, and I get the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.8.1+cpu
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.8.1+cpu
```

Later I tried to simplify the command to just `“pip install torch”`, which causes:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘tools.nnwrap’
ERROR: Failed building wheel for torch
...
Running setup.py clean for torch
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for torch
```

I’d be glad if you could help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but it was because of my internet connection. Can you confirm that you have access to this [URL](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html)?

If it is okay, it may be because of your Python version. Which version are you on? PyTorch 1.8.1 works only with python 3.6+ and does not support 3.5 and below anymore.